# How to design tables such that a person can work for many companies?

Tags: database-design, normalization

Database design such that a person can work for many companies?

Comment: @JustinCave did a good answer, but then I would insert a third column there, specifying the role or profile for that user in each company.

Comment: And I don't think this question is too localized. It is a common situation where you want to create a data-base that serves for a multiple application-server where those applications share the same data-base in some tables, like the users tables and clients tables...

Comment: @EASI: Justin's answer solves the basic problem of tying a person to multiple companies as stated in the question. Nothing prohibits you from expanding the proposed many-to-many table once you've decided to go with the idea.

Comment: Yes but the question is closed, I can't propose a new answer.

Answer (score 6):

You'd need a many-to-many table that maps people to companies.  Something like (I'm guessing at your table definitions)

```
CREATE TABLE employment (
  person_id INTEGER REFERENCES person ( person_id ),
  company_id INTEGER REFERENCES company ( company_id ),
  CONSTRAINT pk_employment PRIMARY KEY ( person_id, company_id )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Justin and ypercube. I had understood the concept better